# HTML navigation bar not going to the top

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. Recently, I have been working around navigation bars and I encountered a problem. This navigation bar will not go to the top. By that I mean its coordination is supposed to be X:0 Y:0 but it keeps on staying at the center of the page. I can't think of anything. Can someone help me please?

**Current code:**

```css
.buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.innerContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: top 40px;
  left: 60px;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.Textarea {
  border: black;
  font-family: cursive;
  padding: 100px;
}

.navBar {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gainsboro;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navBar:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#Title {
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Notepad.css">
  <title>Notepad</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="device-width" height="device-height"></canvas>
  <div class="navBar" onclick="toHomePage()">
    <div>
      <h1 id="Title">SomeRandomWebsite</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <div>
      <button onclick="Saves()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><h3>Save</h3></button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="Clear()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"><h3>Clear</h3></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
      <textarea id="Text" class="Textarea" placeholder="Click to Type" maxlength="1000" cols="20"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="Notepad.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `canvas` element creating the space above the `navbar`, removing it solves the issue.

```css
.buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.innerContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: top 40px;
  left: 60px;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.Textarea {
  border: black;
  font-family: cursive;
  padding: 100px;
}

.navBar {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gainsboro;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navBar:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#Title {
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Notepad.css">
  <title>Notepad</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navBar" onclick="toHomePage()">
    <div>
      <h1 id="Title">SomeRandomWebsite</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <div>
      <button onclick="Saves()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><h3>Save</h3></button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="Clear()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"><h3>Clear</h3></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
      <textarea id="Text" class="Textarea" placeholder="Click to Type" maxlength="1000" cols="20"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="Notepad.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line on you html is the cause because you declare it first (it create blank space on top of page)

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="device-width" height="device-height"></canvas>
```

maybe you need change it orders first to this in html file

```
<body>
<div class="navBar" onclick="toHomePage()">
        <div>
            <h1 id="Title">SomeRandomWebsite</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="device-width" height="device-height"></canvas>
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <div>
            <button onclick="Saves()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><h3>Save</h3></button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="Clear()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"><h3>Clear</h3></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <div class="innerContainer">
            <textarea id="Text" class="Textarea" placeholder="Click to Type" maxlength="1000" cols="20"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="Notepad.js"></script>
</body>
```

or you can delete this line on html

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="device-width" height="device-height"></canvas>
```